# Latexmk not Executing in VimTeX / TeX Live Utility Installation Chronically Failing

Tags: texlive, latexmk, vim-latex

### The Problem (Overview)

`latexmk` is not initializing in Neovim when I open a `*.tex` file.  Furthermore, installation chronically fails when I attempt to install/reinstall `latexmk` using the TeX Live Utility.

### The Problem (Detailed)

I'm a Neovim user looking to begin learning how to take notes & create academic papers using LaTeX.  To this end, I recently:

- Installed MacTex on my Macbook (running Catalina Version 10.15.7).
- Installed [VimTeX plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) via my `init.vim` plugin manager.
- Configured VimTex via my `init.vim` using the following settings:

```
let g:vimtex_view_method='skim'
let g:vimtex_quickfix_enabled=0
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
set conceallevel=2
```

However, when I open a `*.tex` file in Neovim, I receive the following errors:

```
VimTeX: latexmk is not executable
VimTeX: Compiler was not initialized!
```

A bit of sleuthing turned up [this old TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255753/latexmk-command-not-found-on-os-x) which appeared to reference a near identical error.  Opening TeX Live Utility on my machine and searching for "latexmk" under Packages shows that `universal-darwin` is installed on my machine; however, attempting to reinstall `universal-darwin` (or any of the other versions of `latexmk`) consistently returns an "Install failed" message.

Opening the log reveals:

```
2022-09-05 00:20:50 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _isCorrectDatabaseVersionAtURL:][7166]   Checking database version in case preferences have been changed…
2022-09-05 00:20:50 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _installPackagesWithNames:reinstall:][7166]  Beginning install of (
    latexmk
)
from https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/
2022-09-05 00:20:50 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][7166]   Checking code signature before running tlu_ipctask as root…
2022-09-05 00:20:50 +0000 Notice /usr/bin/codesign[7166]    /Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/tlu_ipctask: valid on disk
/Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/tlu_ipctask: satisfies its Designated Requirement
2022-09-05 00:20:50 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][7166]   Signature was valid, okay to run tlu_ipctask
2022-09-05 00:20:54 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][7166]   Invoking privileged task via AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges
2022-09-05 00:20:54 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[15405] dropped privileges to user nobody
2022-09-05 00:20:55 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setWrapperPID:][7166] tlu_ipctask checking in:  tlu_ipctask pid = 15405
2022-09-05 00:20:56 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setUnderlyingPID:][7166]  tlu_ipctask checking in: pid = 15406 (/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr --machine-readable --repository https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/ --persistent-downloads install --reinstall latexmk)
2022-09-05 00:20:56 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[15405] tlu_ipctask: child HOME = '/var/root'
2022-09-05 00:20:56 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[15405] tlu_ipctask: current HOME = '/var/empty'
2022-09-05 00:20:58 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[15405]    start load https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/
2022-09-05 00:20:59 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[15405]    finish load https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/
2022-09-05 00:20:59 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[15405]    tlmgr: Terminating; please see warning above!
2022-09-05 00:20:59 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[15405] location-url    https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/
2022-09-05 00:21:00 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][7166] kqueue noted that pid 15406 exited (/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr --machine-readable --repository https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/ --persistent-downloads install --reinstall latexmk)
2022-09-05 00:21:00 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[15405] child process pid = 15406 exited
2022-09-05 00:21:01 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[15405] exit status of pid = 15406 was 255
2022-09-05 00:21:01 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][7166] exit status of pid = 15405 was 255
2022-09-05 00:21:01 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][7166] kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 15405) exited with status 255
```

To add to the confusion, although TeX Live Utility indicates that `latexmk` *is* installed, it is *not* available on the command line:

```
$ latexmk
zsh: command not found: latexmk
```

Furthermore - and I'm not sure if this is related at all to this issue, but I'll mention it here just in case - running `tlmgr` on the command line returns the same message:

```
$ tlmgr
zsh: command not found: tlmgr
```

As I mentioned earlier, I'm new to LaTex, so I'm afraid this problem is completely opaque to me.  I *presume* the issues with the compiler will resolve if I can get `latexmk` to work...but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Any insight, help, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `latexmk` work from the command line?

Comment: Excellent question!  It does not.  I have edited my original post to reflect this important piece of information.

Comment: So it sounds like your shell isn't recognising the distro installation, presumably even `pdflatex` isn't working from terminal? Are you able to run latex through a gui? Given [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/656166/) have you restarted since installing?

Comment: Are the binaries in your `PATH`?

Comment: @DaiBowen, to answer your questions: (1) Yes, `pdflatex` generates a `zsh: command not found: pdflatex` command line error; (2) Yes, I _am_ able to run LaTeX via the LaTexiT auto-installed by/within MacTex; (3) Yes, I have restarted my Macbook since installing.

Comment: Forgive me, @frabjous.  Although I understand the basics of what `PATH` is and how it works, in situations like this I find I learn more from experienced users when I ask questions that presume zero previous knowledge of Unix, Linux, the CLI, etc..  That said: (1) I'm running Zsh.  How can I check the binaries in my `PATH`?; (2) Where would I likely find MacTex's binaries on my machine? (Currently accessing MacTex via the `Applications` folder on my Mac); (3) What is the best/most efficient way to add those binaries to my `PATH`?

Comment: You can type `echo $PATH` in the terminal to see your current PATH. What you'll get is a list of folders separated by colons `:`. These are where commands are looked for. I think it's already clear that they *aren't* in your path or you wouldn't be getting those "command not found" errors. I use linux, not mac, so I don't know where MacTeX installs its binaries, but part of the log you posted makes it look like `/Library/TeX/texbin` is one place to look. You could add it to your PATH with `export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH`, but that will only be active in that shell or any subshells.

Comment: If editing your `PATH` helps and you want to make it permanent, I don't know from firsthand experience the best way to do that on a mac so it also affects programs launched from the GUI (I only know how I'd do it on linux), but [this article](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/) suggests editing to `/etc/paths`. To be clear, I don't know how to solve your problem, but this might help pinpoint the cause.

Comment: GMRA @frabjous!  Editing my `.zshrc` to include `export PATH="/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH"` worked like a charm.  `latexmk` is now running from the command line and VimTeX is no longer throwing errors when I open a `*.tex` file in Neovim.